# Find circles image processing

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, geometry, hough-transform

I'm using opencv and java to find circles on an image, I have the image below so far.
I'm using Hough to find the circles with the code like this:

```
    Imgproc.medianBlur(result, result, 3);
    Imgproc.medianBlur(result, result, 3);
    Imgproc.medianBlur(result, result, 3);
    Mat circles = new Mat();
    Imgproc.HoughCircles(result, circles, Imgproc.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 1, 200, 100, 30, 40);
    System.out.println(circles.dump());
```

But I get an empty Mat for result with and without the blur. 
How should I fix this code?

[image]

**EDIT :**
Hi guys!

Thanks to you I have this picture now. I'm using these parameters:

```
Imgproc.HoughCircles(result, circles, Imgproc.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 20, 50, 10, 10, 40);
```

I'm still using the medianBlur before the detection.

The only question left is why does it detect these small circles? I've attached the result of the canny detection, I think the circles are pretty seeable .

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the `circles` structure should not be `cv::Mat` but should be `std::vector<cv::Vec3f>`; I think that is why you aren't getting any results.. Please refer to the documentation on the [HoughCircles](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=houghcircles#houghcircles) for details..

Playing around with the values for 5 minutes, I have this starting point for you:

[image]

The parameters I used are,

```
cv::medianBlur(test_Circle, test_Circle, 7);
std::vector<cv::Vec3f> circles; // <- not that "circles" is not cv::Mat
cv::HoughCircles(test_Circle, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 1, 300, 10, 10, 50);
```

You can get much more defined result after you played around with the values a bit.

PS - Since I am a C++ user, please excuse me for putting all my structures in that format. You can easily extend the logic to Java. :)

Comment: Mat can be used as container for vector of points in OpenCV. Most of the functions that accept vector of points will accept Mat and work properly with it. Actually few versions of OpenCV ago some functions required casting vector to Mat. But I am agree that using Mat instead of vector is sort of confusing.

Comment: I'm using Mat, because the function requires a Mat in Java, and I got only 3 value in the Mat when I found only one circle. @MichaelBurdinov

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you are providing radius and not diameter? Try wider range of radiuses (10-100 for example).

Using OpenCV to cheat in Zuma? :)

Answer (score 1):

I've tested my code, it writtent in C# (i think java is the same) and get the result:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUqbh.png)

You can find my code in HoughAlgorithm.cs class
My demo Project [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38282974/open-cv-hough-circle-detection-count-missing-some-objects)

```
    //DP_Resolution: 1
//MinDistance :32
//CannyThreshold: 10
//AccuThreshold: 10
//MinRadius: 13
//MaxRadius: 20

public static CvSeq DetectCircles(IplImage pImage, CamEnum _camName)
{
    try
    {
        CvMemStorage memStorage = cvlib.CvCreateMemStorage(0);
        return cvlib.CvHoughCircles(ref pImage, memStorage.ptr, 3, 1, 32, 10, 10, 13, 20);
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUqbh.png

Comment: You seem to have a lot of false positives.